# InteliJ Maven unit test execution classpath

Tags: java, maven, junit, classpath

I'm working on maven project using InteliJ. Typical scenario is that I execute:

```
mvn clean install
```

to build my module. mvn compiles src/java/main and src/java/test into target/classes and target/test-classes respectively. I also noticed that target/classes classes are being copied into target/test-classes.

What is my pain - when I modify src/main/java src code and run JUnit test from InteliJ - it doesn't see modified code. The src/main/java is being compiled into target/classes but not into target/test-classes. This behavior forces me to recompile all using mvn (not the best efficiency...). I'm looking for advice how to improve this. Possible solutions:

1. Avoid copying target/classes into target/test-classes - this may be still required so sound like dummy idea. But how to control this process?
2. Configure InteliJ to compile classes end copy them into target/test-classes
3. Change the order on classpath - currently it is target/test-classes and target/classes. Having them in opposite order would solve the issue too. Hot to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there isn't "Build" step in the run configuration. Check "Before launch" section in "Run/debug configuration" and add "Build" if it's missing.

Comment: As described this configuration is correct - InteliJ is doing rebuild but classes are not being copied into target/test-classes (new classes are placed in target/classes). Point 2 is is possibility to fix it - how to add this "copy" step as part of standards "Build" step?

Comment: Very strange. "Build" step in JUnit run configuration should do exactly that. I would also recommend to check "Test ouptup path" value in Project Structure -> Modules -> "your module" -> Paths (should be like "<module path>/target/test-classes" as opposite to "<module path>/target/classes" for "Output path")